# Radio button color is black in IE 11 but blue in IE 8 by default. How to make radio button of IE 11 same like IE 8?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I don't think any description is required. I just need my IE 11 radio button to be same like in IE 8 i.e. like 3-d blue in color.
In IE 11 the default radio button is 2-d and black in color. 
No solution for this uptill now.

Answer (score 2):

Check this demo

```css
input::-ms-check {
    color: #32CAFF;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input::-ms-check {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" />
```

```css
input::-ms-check {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" />
```

This appears as black not red.

Answer (score 0):

The radio input is incredibly difficult to style consistently across browsers, nigh on impossible in some.

One trick to make them consistent, though, is to actually move them off screen, making sure that their labels appear immediately after them in your HTML, and then use the labels pseudo elements to create your own version of the input, whose styles you can change based on the state of the actual input.

Here's a quick example to illustrate the concept:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
input[type=radio]{
    left:-9999px;
    position:absolute;
}
label{
    display:block;
    font-family:arial;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
input[type=radio]+label::before{
    background-clip:content-box;
    border:1px solid #009;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    height:12px;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:2px;
    transition:background .25s linear;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:12px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+label::before{
    background-color:#009;
}
```

```html
<input checked="checked" id="first" name="radio" type="radio" value="1">
<label for="first">Label 1</label>
<input id="second" name="radio" type="radio" value="2">
<label for="second">Label 2</label>
```